# Оформление списка, идущего сразу после подзаголовка

Tags: пунктуация, список

Как правильно оформить элементы списка – с прописной буквы или строчной? Априори подзаголовок не может заканчиваться двоеточием, отсюда сомнения.

**Состав, описание ингредиентов** (это подзаголовок)

- кофе молотый – 1 ст. л.;
- сахар – 2 ст. л.;
- молоко – 3 ст. л.

Важное уточнение! Список нельзя оформить в виде таблицы или еще как-то "поиграть" с его видом путем графического редактирования. Требуется лишь решение вопроса – прописной или строчной должна быть первая буква **в списке после подзаголовка**.

Comment: Как по-русски будет "априори"?

Comment: edem, "априори" в данном контексте можно понимать как "само собой", "по умолчанию", "обязательное условие к оформлению подзаголовков, не обсуждаемое и не подлежащее изменениям". То есть вот не могут заголовки и подзаголовки заканчиваться двоеточием, и это надо принять как данность.

Comment: А как может быть награда в +100 баллов репутации, если у вас только 98 баллов?

Comment: Ответ лежит на поверхности: до назначения награды у меня было 198 баллов.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим в контексте грамматики.

**Первое слово в предложении должно быть с большой буквы.**

Тогда получается так:

- Кофе молотый – 1 ст. л.;
- сахар – 2 ст. л.;
- молоко – 3 ст. л.

(Зрительно не очень, хоть и грамматически верно.)

И второй вариант - каждый элемент как предложение:

- Кофе молотый – 1 ст. л.
- Сахар – 2 ст. л.
- Молоко – 3 ст. л.

(Этот вариант выигрывает у первого и смотрится нормально.)

Примечание: в других вариантах правило большой буквы будет нарушаться.

Answer (score 0):

Если писать с большой буквы, то после каждого элемента должна быть точка (а не точка с запятой). Это актуально для предложений, длинных фраз, когда каждый элемент представляет собой самостоятельную мысль. В этом случае пункт списка часто состоит из нескольких предложений.

Для ингредиентов вариант с маленькой буквы оптимальный. Более того, ингредиенты с большой буквы будут смотреться очень странно.

Answer (score 0):

Тут противоречивые рекомендации в отношении оформления подобных списков.
Но у вас вообще элементы списка заканчиваются точкой с запятой, так что заглавная неуместна нигде, кроме разве что первого элемента.

Думаю, что и его следует писать со строчной - для общности.

И последнее. А заголовок у вас - это как понимать? Это "заголовок" только списка? Тогда нет причин применять к нему "правило" о том, что он не может ничем кончаться. Смело ставьте двоеточие.

Comment: Имеется в виду именно подзаголовок к одному из разделов статьи. Н1 –название статьи, Н2, Н3 – подзаголовки следующих уровней. В моем вопросе это подзаголовок Н3, и сразу после него у автора идет список.

Answer (score 0):

При нежелании заказчика (оно же и невозможность для исполнителя) придерживаться норм пунктуации — путь к конфликту с работодателем или правилом. Есть путь графического редактирования: по-разному, в том числе заливкой и/или линией, как показано здесь, — зафиксировать границы блока списка на поле страницы. Такое решение позволяет убрать и тчк/зпт.

Состав, описание ингредиентов

```
кофе молотый – 1 ст. л.
сахар – 2 ст. л.
молоко – 3 ст. л.
```

Состав, описание ингредиентов

---

кофе молотый — 1 ст. л.

сахар – 2 ст. л.

молоко – 3 ст. л.

---

Comment: Тут всё дело в том, что я занимаюсь проверкой грамотности статей, а не оформлением. И функций редактора у меня тоже нет, только корректорские. Заказчик, естественно, требует соблюдения норм пунктуации. Похоже, тупиковая ситуация с этими списками...

Answer (score 0):

Такой есть вариант. Но тогда количество ингредиентов правильнее оформлять отдельной колонкой. И так смотрится гораздо лучше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]